# Link Read More on a Newsletter HTML

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, newsletter, mhtml

I want to insert on my newsletter (HTML) a tipical link "Read more ... " that expand/hide my news inside of my email with more info (more text). How can i do this for works on mail platforms (gmail,outlook..?

I know how to do that on a web page using javascript like this but on an email this doesnt works.

```
< html>
...

< script type='text/JavaScript'>
function verocultar(cual) {
var c=cual.nextSibling;

if(c.style.display=='none') {
c.style.display='block';
} else {
c.style.display='none'; }
return false;
}

</ script>

...

< p>Fusce tempor ....< / p>

< a  onclick="return verocultar(this);" href="javascript:void(0);">< img src="images/read-more-btn.gif" alt="Read More" width="102" height="27" border="0">< / a> < p>As you look out on that coupon- and candy-trimmed future, we're sure you're reflecting on all that has gone by this year: All the milestones and memories. All the mistakes and monstrosities.
     Cloth.< / p>

....

< / html>
```

Comment: You can't. It wont be supported globally. You should give up on this idea anyway

Comment: look at mailchimp.com or salesforce

Comment: I would have to agree with the 2 answers above. I have spent much time playing around with emailers... do not try to get too complicated, cause as soon as you do, it will start to have varying results in the different mail clients.

Comment: Most of the Email clients do not support tags in the head sections like <link>, <style> etc. So you better not to use any javascripts inside the mail newsletter. Try to open it in a new window with full contents.

Comment: Yes but i need display the hidden text... Its for a company and so i cant open a pop up browser, i need show the contens inside of the email newsletter.

Comment: @user1901142 I just added a link to my answer that might help

Answer (score 3):

Javascript does not work in most (if not all) email clients.

EDIT: Ros from Campaign Monitor has a css powered technique that [works on the mac clients](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/18/from-monitor-to-mobile-optimizing-email-newsletters-with-css/) (It is about a third of the way down the page)

Comment: … therefore you cannot. Link to a website if you want interactive content.

Comment: I know that but i would like to find the way and interact since newsletter-mail platform.

Comment: email is only html and limited css. All the bells and whistles of modern day web aren't available. Any solution you find won't be widely supported.